# python: global name not defined

Tags: python, opencv, numpy

So I'm using opencv, numpy, and python for a computer vision project. I'm going off of this tutorial: http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.org/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_feature2d/py_features_harris/py_features_harris.html
and have followed it exactly (minus a few minor changes which are apparent in the code). I'm not sure why I'm getting this error (below) and would really appreciate some insight on this. Thanks!

Code:

```
def applyHarrisCornerDetection():
    image1 = cv2.imread('pictures/board1.png')
    image2 = cv2.imread('pictures/board2.png')

    gray1 = cv2.cvtColor(image1,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    gray2 = cv2.cvtColor(image2,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    gray1 = np.float32(gray1)
    gray2 = np.float32(gray2)

    dst1 = cv2.cornerHarris(gray1,2,3,0.04)
    dst2 = cv2.cornerHarris(gray2,2,3,0.04)

    dst1 = cv2.dilate(dst1,None)
    dst2 = cv2.dilate(dst2,None)

    img1[dst1>0.01*dst1.max()]=[0,0,255]
    img2[dst2>0.01*dst2.max()]=[0,0,255]

    cv2.imshow('dst1',img1)
    cv2.imshow('dst2',img2)

    if cv2.waitKey(0) & 0xff == 27:
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Error:
[image]

Comment: Your code does not define any variable called `img1`, and neither does the code on the page you showed.  What do you expect `img1` to be?

Comment: quite embarrassing. I appreciate the help. haha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because of these two lines:

```
img1[dst1>0.01*dst1.max()]=[0,0,255]
img2[dst2>0.01*dst2.max()]=[0,0,255]
```

You are assigning elements to some position in a list, but that list hasn't been initialized.